# ArcGIS Data Store backup to Azure with configurebackuplocation.bat fails?

Tags: arcgis-server, azure

I'm attempting to create a secondary backup location for my ArcGIS Data Store into an Azure Blob container. I've been following the instructions https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/data-store-utility-reference.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_35FC910709804CC0AA43C44C5B15F810 and https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/data-store-backups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_BA5A32CD1AB740EC8C502ED8720ECFE2.

I've tried to run the configurebackuplocation.bat and get the not very useful error

`Invalid parameter ((storage location))`

[image: configurebackuplocation.bat error]

```
PS C:\ArcGIS\DataStore\tools> .\configurebackuplocation --operation register --location type=azure;location=gisdatastorebackup;name=gisdsbackup;username=$usr;password=$pwd
You are attempting to change the backup location of the data store. For a relational data store, existing backups will be copied to the new location and it could take a few moments. For a spatiotemporal big data store, the data store service could be restarted. Please do not interrupt the process once it has started.

Do you wish to continue (Yes or No)?yes

Error encountered: Machine 'https://machinename.guid.PX.INTERNAL.CLOUDAPP.NET:2443/arcgis/datastoreadmin' returned an error. 'Invalid parameter ((storage location)).'

location=gisdatastorebackup : The term 'location=gisdatastorebackup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:70
+ ... on register --location type=azure;location=gisdatastorebackup;name=gi ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (location=gisdatastorebackup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

name=gisdsbackup : The term 'name=gisdsbackup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... ation type=azure;location=gisdatastorebackup;name=gisdsbackup;usernam ...
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (name=gisdsbackup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

username=$usr : The term 'username=$usr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:115
+ ... re;location=gisdatastorebackup;name=gisdsbackup;username=$usr;passwor ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (username=$usr:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

password=$pwd : The term 'password=$pwd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:129
+ ... ation=gisdatastorebackup;name=gisdsbackup;username=$usr;password=$pwd
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (password=$pwd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\ArcGIS\DataStore\tools>
```

I've ensured that my blob container is ready and my parameters appear ok. I haven't been able to find anything about this error or anyone with the same issue.

Has anyone had a similar experience with this utility?

Comment: Red and black on dark blue is *spectacularly* illegible. All the more reason to capture and present the output/error text as ASCII in the question.

Comment: Seconding Vinces request. Please copy and paste in plain text.

Comment: @Vince Good point. I've added the ASCII in the code block.